# if statement with grep

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, scripting

What I'm trying to do is the get the user input and search through the file, If it match it will show the result, else it will echo $keyword not found.

But my scrip is always return fault.

```
       read -p "Enter keyword: " keyword
       if search="$(cat ./records | grep '$keyword')"
       then
       echo "$search"
       else
        echo "$keyword not found!"
       fi ;;
```

Comment: the error is that you are using `'$keyword'`. within single quotes the variable is not expanded and treated as text. use `"$keyword"` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
read -r -p 'Enter pattern: ' pattern

result=$( grep -e "$pattern" records )

if [ -n "$result" ]; then
    printf '%s\n' "$result"
else
    printf 'No match found for pattern "%s"\n' "$pattern"
fi
```

- The assignment to `search` (`result` in my code) is best done outside of the `if` statement.
- Test with `-n` ("is this string non-empty?") on the result.
- Don't single-quote the variable (it will prevent the shell from expanding its value). Double quote it instead.
- Notice "pattern" rather than "keyword". The way you use `grep` here will use the user-supplied string as a regular expression (a pattern, such as `cat.*dog`), not necessarily as a plain fixed string.
- `cat` should be used to concatenate files, in most other cases it's more or less useless.
- Use `read -r` to allow the user to enter backslashes.

---

Alternatively:

```
read -r -p 'Enter pattern: ' pattern

if ! grep -e "$pattern" records; then
    printf 'No match found for pattern "%s"\n' "$pattern"
fi
```

This avoids storing a potentially huge amount of data in a shell variable and instead relies on the exit status of `grep` to tell whether the pattern may be found in the file or not. If the pattern is found, the matching lines will be printed (and nothing more has to be done).

Regarding the use of `printf` in place of `echo`: [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)

---

Shorter, using a short-circuit OR.

```
read -r -p 'Enter pattern: '

grep -e "$REPLY" records ||
printf 'No match found for pattern "%s"\n' "$REPLY"
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, It works ! I learn something new !!!

Comment: on side note alternative is useful only if you don't intend to reuse grep's result.

Comment: @Archemar If you want to use the result of `grep` it is _often_ the case that you should write it in `awk` instead :-)

Comment: Hi again, I just wonder how do i modify the script if the user dont provide input (eg. just press enter or return key). do i just elseif?

Comment: @PrinPuyakul You may use `if [ -z "$pattern" ]; then ... fi` to do something if the pattern in `$pattern` is empty.

Comment: @Kusalananda ok, but I thought -n is to check the empty string? -z is share similarity ?

Comment: @PrinPuyakul `-n` checks for a non-empty string, `-z` checks for an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

See below:

```
read -p "Enter keyword: " keyword

if search=$(grep "$keyword" ./records)
        then
                echo "$search"
        else
                echo "$keyword not found!"
        fi
```

1. Don't use quotting with `$()` as @jasonwryan was noted above
2. Not nesessary to use `cat` piping with `grep`. Use `grep <pattern> file` instead
3. Delete `;;` after `fi`

Comment: Thanks so much you solution is working too!! ";;" cos its in my Switch case but thanks for point it out ^^"